# How do you test whether both sides of an array total the same? | Javascript Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question**

You are going to be given an array of integers. Your job is to take that array and find an index N where the sum of the integers to the left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.

For example:

Let's say you are given the array {1,2,3,4,3,2,1}: Your function will return the index 3, because at the 3rd position of the array, the sum of left side of the index ({1,2,3}) and the sum of the right side of the index ({3,2,1}) both equal 6.

**Answer**

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr){
  
  for(let i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
    
       let arr1 = arr.slice(0, (arr[i] - 1));
       let arr2 = arr.slice((arr[i] + 1),);
       
      let arr11 = arr1.reduce((total, item)=>{
         return total + item;
       }, 0);

      let arr22 = arr2.reduce((total, item)=>{
         return total + item;
       }, 0);

      if(arr11 === arr22){
        return arr[i];
      }

  }

  return -1;

}


console.log(findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
console.log(findEvenIndex([1, 100, 50, -51, 1, 1]))
console.log(findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3,4,5,6]))
```

I can't see an error here, but it yields incorrect results. Any ideas?

Comment: `let arr1 = arr.slice(0, (arr[i] - 1));` why are you slicing using the value of the index in the array?

Comment: You need to return `i`, not `arr[i]` (also, yes: `i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++` and use `i` for the slice command, not the arbitrary number stored in the array)

Comment: function findEvenIndex(arr){
  
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    
       let arr1 = arr.slice(0, (i - 1));
       let arr2 = arr.slice((i + 1),);
       
      let arr11 = arr1.reduce((total, item)=>{
         return total + item;
       }, 0);

      let arr22 = arr2.reduce((total, item)=>{
         return total + item;
       }, 0);

      if(arr11 === arr22){
        return i;
      }

  }

  return -1;

}
still provides the wrong output

Comment: You don't really need to use `.slice()` at all; the numbers are already sitting there in the array, so making lots of copies of parts of the array is wasteful.

Comment: Fix with `slice()`: https://jsfiddle.net/ng1uL3qo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this part:

```
   let arr1 = arr.slice(0, (arr[i] - 1));
   let arr2 = arr.slice((arr[i] + 1),);
```

This is incorrect: `arr[i]`. That is a *value*, eg in `[2,4,6,8,10]` `arr[3]==8`. You want to slice on the index itself:

```
   let arr1 = arr.slice(0, i - 1);
   let arr2 = arr.slice(i + 1,);
```

---

Please note: There is another error in the two lines :) I leave that to you. Hint: you're now slicing two values out of the array instead of one. Perform the following code in your head first, then somewhere where you verify your results.

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4]
let x = 2;
console.log(arr.slice(0, x - 1));
console.log(arr.slice(x + 1,));
```

Comment: You need brackets inside the slice function right? My formula still doesn't work :'D

Comment: This is definitely an improvement, but when `i` is zero the wrong thing will happen.

Comment: Not the brackets, the code is syntactically correct :) I've added a nudge in the direction of the solution

Comment: @Pointy Correct. But the correct solution doesnt either. Im leaving edge cases out of it for simplicity sake

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the array method [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), which, we shouldn't be surprised to learn, finds an index in an array subject to a certain condition.

```js
const sum = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((total, n) => total + n, 0)

const findBalancedIndex = (ns) => 
  ns .findIndex ((_, i) => sum (ns.slice (0, i)) === sum (ns.slice (i + 1)))


console .log (findBalancedIndex ([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
console .log (findBalancedIndex ([1, 100, 50, -51, 1, 1]))
console .log (findBalancedIndex ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Here we include a simple helper function to find the sum of an array, and then we pass a function to `findIndex` which uses it twice on the elements before the index and those after it.  We use the second parameter of the callback function, the `index` to do this.  This means we are skipping the first parameter altogether, and rather than naming it with something like `n`, we use the somewhat common convention of calling it `_`, signalling a placeholder we won't use.  Note that you don't need to subtract one from the right-hand boundary of `slice`, since that boundary value is already excluded.  And of course, others have pointed out that you need to slice to the index and not the array value at that index.

This finds the *first* correct index.  You would have to use a different technique if you wanted to find *all* such indices.  (That it's possible to have more than one should be clear from arrays like `[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1]` -- the indices for all those `0`s would work.)

Answer (score 1):

you return arr[i] when you need to return just i

Comment: While correct, here on SO we prefer little examples. Sometimes that says more than any normal text can :)